# Phpunit can't find abstract class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

For some reason when I try to test abstract class I  get `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: Class "AbstractClass" does not exist.`

Here's the code

AbstractClass.php

```
<?php 
namespace SD\Project;

abstract class AbstractClass 
{
  public function handle()
  {

  }
}
```

AbstractClassTest.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'AbstractClass.php';

use SD\Project\AbstractClass;

class AbstractClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
 public function testHandle()
 {
   $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('AbstractClass');
 }
}
```

When I get rid off the namespace and use statements the code is executed successfully. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the fully qualified path of the class.

```
$stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\SD\Project\AbstractClass');
```

Read Similar: [PHPUnit, Interfaces and Namespaces (Symfony2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154471/phpunit-interfaces-and-namespaces-symfony2)

Examples: http://theaveragedev.com/testing-abstract-classes-with-phpunit/